# Consulta desde dos datos - PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Quizás esto es simple, pero la verdad es que no se como resolverlo. Estoy tratando de obtener una lista de horarios y fechas desde dos `id`, pero no logro obtener bueno resultados.

Tabla horastrabajadas

```
id | idtrabajador | idtrabajo | horastotal | fecha
-------------------------------------------------------
1  | 3            | 8         | 8          | 2019-09-02
2  | 2            | 8         | 6          | 2019-09-02
3  | 3            | 8         | 10         | 2019-09-02
```

Consulta PHP

```
<?php

$idp = $_GET['trabajoid']; // id del trabajo = 8
$userid = $row_u['id']; // id del trabajor = 3

$list = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM horastrabajadas WHERE idtrabajador = '".$userid."' AND WHERE idtrabajo = '".$idp."'");
while ($fila = $list->fetch()) {
?>
<div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
<?=$fila['fecha'];?>
<span><?=$fila['horastotal'];?> hs.</span>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

El resultado que debería tener es este:

```
Día         -  Horas por día
----------------------------
2019-09-02  -  8hs
2019-09-02  -  10hs
```

Pero no lo obtengo, me lista todos los trabajadores con sus horas y no se como resolverlo. Agradezco de antemano la ayuda!

Comment: El `$row_u` es porque el trabajador esta registrado y de esa manera obtengo su `id`, asi: `$user = $_SESSION['usuario']; 
$userl = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM trabajador WHERE usuario = '".$user."'"); 
$row_u = $userl->fetch();
$userid = $row_u['id'];`

Comment: el `id` de trabajador

Comment: Borrá el segundo `WHERE`. La sintaxis es `WHERE idtrabajador = 3 AND idtrabajo = 8`.

Comment: Aaah.... no sabia eso... soy un estupido! Muchas gracias!